# ZSH autocomplete: Highlight prefix of suggestions which is already typed

Tags: zsh

I have configured ZSH to have bash-like autocomplete with

```
setopt noautomenu
setopt nomenucomplete
```

So on pressing tab, it only completes to the prefix that is unique among all suggestions and on pressing tab a second time, it shows a list of all possible completions with this prefix.
Is there a way to highlight the part in the suggestions that is already typed?

So for example if "do" is typed and tab is pressed two times to show the suggestions, it would show something like:

> **do**cuments
>
> **do**wnloads
>
> **do**cker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing that's shipped with zsh is the [`show-ambiguity` style](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-show_002dambiguity_002c-completion-style). It highlights the first character that isn't already typed.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' show-ambiguity true
```

The default highlighting is underline. You can replace `true` by `1` for bold, `'1;31'` for bold red, `1;41` for bold and a red background, etc.

In addition to not being exactly what you want, it has the major downside of [suppressing the coloring of file names according to their type](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.9/Completion/Base/Core/_setup#L25). Given how [it is handled deep inside `_main_complete`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.9/Completion/Base/Core/_main_complete#L377), it looks really difficult to tune how it works without patching the zsh code.